# Script Argument matching

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

Does PowerShell do some sort of nearest match or autocompletion when dealing with arguments passed to a script? Given this code...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [string][Alias("aS")] $applySet,
    [string][Alias("cS")] $conformSet,

    [string][Alias("sL")] $setList,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)][Object[]]$extraParameters = @()
)

Write-Host "s:  $set"
Write-Host "sL: $setList"
Write-Host "aS: $applySet"
Write-Host "cS: $conformSet"
Write-Host "X:  $extraParameters"
```

If I use **-junk "junk"** in the script shortcut I get that info in `$extraParameters` as expected. Misspelling something, say **-aplySet**, also shows up as an extra parameter. However, using **-set** actually populates the `$setList` variable rather than `$extraParameters` as I would expect.

Verified in PowerShell 2.0 and 5.1. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell allows using the initial characters of a parameter name as long as they are unambiguous.

Comment: Hmm, I "guess" that make sense. At least in a scripting language. Kinda wish it could be toggled off, like I wish pipelined output could be. At least with command line arguments. But for now I guess I need to document the behavior for people, and stop trying to catch certain errors that to PS really aren't errors.

Comment: It's useful behavior at the command-line (quicker to type), but best-practice in a script is to spell everything out.

Comment: Exactly. And I want to catch every "inappropriate" use. But this seems to circumvent that, in that I can't properly catch -set as an error, because PowerShell automatically assumes -setlist was meant. And we all know about assuming. ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is somewhat undocumented, as far as I can tell.

- [`about_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847824.aspx) doesn't mention the use of abbreviated parameters.
- [`about_Command_Syntax`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847867.aspx) talks about using parameters but not short versions.
- I `Save-Help`'d all the help and <strike>grep</strike> sls'd it for likely terms, couldn't see anything relevant.
- [This blog post from 2006](https://poshoholic.com/2007/09/06/essential-powershell-avoid-shorthand-in-shared-powershell-scripts/) talks about it, so it has been in PowerShell since version 1.0

> In PowerShell 1.0, part of the parameter name resolution logic includes support for identifying parameters by the shortest substring that uniquely identifies the parameter or an alias to the parameter when compared with a list of parameters and aliases for the cmdlet.

and it's mentioned in PowerShell developer Bruce Payette's book 'PowerShell In Action', chapter 2, P.39-40:

> The piece of the PowerShell interpreter that figures all of this out is called the parameter binder. The parameter binder is smart - it doesn’t require that you specify the full name of a parameter as long as you specify enough for it to uniquely distinguish what you mean.

But that's it, no comment on design choice or rationale that I can see. Speculating, as @Mike Shepard comments, PowerShell's dual role as an interactive shell (where people want to type as little as possible, and are writing one-off throwaway commands) and a scripting language (where people want clarity, readability, maintainability by multiple people over longer times) is what gives rise to the short form / long form versions of everything.

```
gci -r | sls (date)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern (Get-Date)
```

- Aliases
- Positional parameter binding, without the parameter name
- Parameter name abbreviation
- Parameter to object property automagic binding
- Command resolution can lookup `Get-` cmdlets if the `Get-` is left out

Fwiw, it appears to be [this line in the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MergedCommandParameterMetadata.cs#L487) of `System.Management.Automation/engine/MergedCommandParameterMetadat.cs`, which someone on the PowerShell Slack identified, which actually does the parameter match:

```cs
foreach (string parameterName in _bindableParameters.Keys)
{
// ---
    if (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IsPrefix(parameterName, name, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase))
// ---
    {
        // If it is an exact match then only return the exact match
        // as the result

        if (tryExactMatching && String.Equals(parameterName, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return _bindableParameters[parameterName];
        }
        else
        {
            matchingParameters.Add(_bindableParameters[parameterName]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great sleuthing. To give the philosophy a name: _elastic syntax_: "PowerShell supports an elastic syntax—concise on the command line and complete in scripts." "Earlier we said that you just needed enough of the parameter name to distinguish it from other command parameters." From the upcoming 3rd edition of "PowerShell in Action" (1st chapter available for free) - https://www.manning.com/books/windows-powershell-in-action-third-edition