# Why does PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem` command resolve the parameter `d` to `Depth`?

Tags: powershell

Given that `Get-ChildItem` has three parameters that begin with the character `D`...

```
❯ (gcm Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Values |? Name -like 'd*' | select name, aliases

Name      Aliases
----      -------
Depth     {}
Debug     {db}
Directory {ad, d}
```

... and that the `Directory` parameter has explicit aliases `ad` and `d`, why does `Get-ChildItem -d` resolve to `Get-ChildItem -Depth`?

```
❯ Get-ChildItem -d
Get-ChildItem: Missing an argument for parameter 'Depth'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.UInt32' and try again.
```

Comment: Not intuitive. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428613/script-argument-matching/40434177#40434177) has a link to seemingly relevant source code https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MergedCommandParameterMetadata.cs#L487

Comment: Looks like `"d"` isn't one of the aliases available when it tries to bind https://i.stack.imgur.com/obwBM.png - so it ends up with `matchingParameters` collection having 2 items "Depth" and "Debug" and only "Depth" is retained by the `DeclaredFormalParameters`/`DynamicParameters` check

Comment: If passing `-ad` the aliased parameter collection has 21 items (now including `d` and `ad`) so looks like that uses more expanded metadata (as second pass when first doesn't match anything) - so need to look into why those 7 aliases aren't included in the first pass

Comment: Debug is a common parameter (about_CommonParameters). I wonder if it just picks the first non-common parameter in alphabetical order? I suppose that's what @MartinSmith means by a declared formal parameter. Frankly, I'd rather the system instead complain about ambiguous parameters like Cisco IOS.

Comment: @BaconBits That's what I would expect is it would throw an error due to either an ambiguous parameter or parameter set.  That's exactly what happens with `GetChildItem -f` (which could match `-Filter`, `-File`, and `-Force` parameters): `Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Filter -Force.`  Note that the `-File` dynamic parameter is not part of that error message.

Comment: @BaconBits - it is not alphabetical. There are 2 values in matchingParameters https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MergedCommandParameterMetadata.cs#L532 and one in filteredParameters when that bit has finished. But it does have exact matching logic for aliases that doesn't kick in as it doesn't consider all aliases in the first attempt https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/MergedCommandParameterMetadata.cs#L514

Comment: I am not sure what you'd expect from doing this... `Get-ChildItem -d` alone would do. You are not giving PowerShell enough to work with. Parameters/switches require information. There are cmdlets to leverage to trace what your command/code is doing. Personally, this is one more reason why aliases suck. Sure we all use them in our interactive/throw-away stuff, but, well, you know. ;-}

Comment: @postanote: I would have expected it to be equivalent to `Get-ChildIten -directory`. @Jaykul's helpful answer below explains why that's not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the other parameters are *dynamic* parameters added at invocation, based on the path you're asking about.

- `-Directory` is only valid when the `Path` is in the FileSystem provider
- `-DnsName` and `-DocumentEncryptionCert` are only valid in the Certificate provider

It's the same with `-re` being `-Recurse` instead of being ambiguous with `-ReadOnly` ...

It's also the same with `-e` being `-Exclude` instead of `-Eku` or `-ExpiriringInDays` ...

And you'll notice that if you run `Get-ChildItem -f` and it tells you `f` is ambiguous, the only options that it suggests are `-Filter` and `-Force`, not `-File` or `-FollowSymlink` which are exclusive to the FileSystem provider...

---

You can see all of that using `Get-Parameter` which you can get from the PowerShell gallery by `Install-Script Get-Parameter`

---

I eventually found a way to show by experimentation that the non-dynamic parameters will *always* get resolved first, and the parameter binder never even looks at the dynamic parameters for anything it can bind without them. Therefore, the parameter selector doesn't even know what the names **or aliases** of the dynamic parameters are *unless* it can't find a match on the non-dynamic parameters. So that `d` alias is just causing confusion, unless it's being generated in such a way that it also shows up on other commands...

Try this:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation
function Test-Alias {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [switch]$Awful
    )

    dynamicparam {
        $paramDictionary = [RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
        $attribs = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
        $attribs.Add([ParameterAttribute]@{ParameterSetName = "_AllParameterSets" })

        $paramdictionary.Add("Automation", [RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new( "Automation", [switch], $attribs))

        $attribs += [AliasAttribute]::new("A", "C")
        $paramdictionary.Add("Architecture", [RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new( "Architecture", [switch], $attribs))
        $paramdictionary
    }
    end {
        $PSBoundParameters
    }
}
```

If you run that in your console, you'll not only be able to see that `Test-Alias -A` uses `Awful` but also that `Test-Alias -C` does work! The A alias never had a chance, but it's not because aliases on dynamic parameters are ignored completely, it's because there was a parameter that started with that letter which was *not dynamic*.

Now try this:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding { Test-Alias -A } -PSHost
```

[image: A screenshot of my output, for the lazy]

And compare that to the output when you use `Test-Alias -C` or `Test-Alias -A -C` ...

You can see that the Dynamic parameters are only considered after everything non-dynamic *that can be bound* has been.

Comment: So is there any value in having the "d" alias defined for Directory?

Comment: There is not, but I'm not 100% sure if the person adding it could tell ;-)

Comment: I've added an example. Remember that in the case of the provider cmdlets (like Get-ChildItem) the dynamic parameters are defined in a completely different place than the other parameters (i.e. in the providers), so it's possible this parameter is used in other commands (I don't think so), or that the person writing it just didn't notice.  Personally, I think it's worth filing a bug to get the alias removed (because the results confuse **me**, and I've been doing this language a long time)...

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, not a complete answer.

I unfortunately can't find the specific terminology (tab completion, maybe?), but it appears to be part of PowerShell's attempt to be helpful. The behaviour as experienced appears to be "when you use a -d, it attempts to expand the command for you". When running `Get-ChildItem -d` and press TAB, it expands to "depth" automatically, even though there's an alias.

This "works" for items without a specific alias as well - the `-recurse` toggle (alias 's') works if you use `-r`, though it's unspecified.

Expected behaviour, I'd expect the tabbing-out of a work while typing to extend to "depth" as the first preferred word, but simply using the alias should act as "-directory". This would likely require a Microsoft change to correct, if they do, as it may break years of existing scripts.

Comment: The question isn't why abbreviations work but why does the abbreviation take precedence over an exact match for the alias

Comment: I agree, I think I didn't put my muddled thoughts in correctly. It's all "as intended" perhaps, but the logic around selection as expected is that an exactly-matching alias should be used first, over a partial parameter name. Tried to mention in the last paragraph.

If you feel the (impartial) answer adds no value, I can delete it

Comment: I don't think this behavior has anything to do with Tab completion, but I believe it cycles through either alphabetically or in declaration order; there is no "preferred" or best match.  Also note that `-Directory` is not suggested by tab completion, anyways, probably because it's a [dynamic attribute from the filesystem provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_FileSystem_Provider?#dynamic-parameters).  Finally, you say "the logic ... is that an exactly-matching alias should be used first" but the observed behavior is the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from my comment.

What you are seeing as the resolution of `-d` to `Depth`, is what IntelliSense default provides. Thus, the same thing will happen in the console host, etc.

[image]

Trace your command, if you want to see what the call stack:

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {Get-ChildItem -d} -PSHost
```

Just as there is a command preference in PowerShell,...

[about_Command_Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7)

... the same applies to parameters, switches, during invocation. Looking at the MS PowerShell Source code, for that cmdlet also should clarify things for you:

snippet

```
...
dynamicparam
{
    try {
        $targetCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ChildItem', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet, $PSBoundParameters)
        $dynamicParams = @($targetCmd.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Where-Object { $_.Value.IsDynamic })
        if ($dynamicParams.Length -gt 0)
        {
            $paramDictionary = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
            foreach ($param in $dynamicParams)
            {
                $param = $param.Value

                if(-not $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.ContainsKey($param.Name))
                {
                    $dynParam = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($param.Name, $param.ParameterType, $param.Attributes)
                    $paramDictionary.Add($param.Name, $dynParam)
                }
            }
            return $paramDictionary
        }
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Or, is intellisense is just getting lucky, because `Depth` happens to come before `Directory` alphabetically?